# How to recover a clobbered LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Ubuntu Linux 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

I would like to find out how to recover a clobbered LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Ubuntu Linux 16.04.

I clobbbered it a few days ago by setting the global environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /home/frankc/DevelopmentX64/Debug in the file /etc/environment and rebooting.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to login to the machine?

Comment: @Stephen Harris, Thank you for your comment. Yes, I can login to the machine. Could you please assist me?

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't have a default value, so you should just be able to delete the line from that file.  If you have commands that are failing then you can do `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your current shell so you can edit the `/etc` file.    If you had a previous value in there then it's non-standard and you'll need to recover the value from a backup.

Comment: @Stephen Harris, Thank you for your excellent comment. If you have time, would you be willing to answer this question and I will be one of the first to upvote your answer?.

Comment: @Stephen Harris, In the Ubuntu 16.04 distribution, where may I find libuser32.dll or libuser32.so? Thank you for your help.

Comment: That sounds like you need to install `wine` - a set of tools that allows you to run (some) windows programs on Linux.  You might want to open a new question detailing what it is you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` entry is left unset, and the system resolver libraries use the cache generated by `ldconfig`, which is configured by `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

So in your case if you didn't have any previous customisations you can simple re-edit `/etc/environment` and delete the line.

If your editor is not working properly you can `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your shell to temporarily let it work.

Note that if did have any customisations then you'll need to restore from backup.

Comment: Thank you for your help  earlier today. How do I reconstruct the LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the wilcard *.conf files in the directory /etc/ld.so.conf.d?